# enumerate function not working

Tags: arcpy, loop, grids-graticules

The following script only gives me a result for the last given grid (grid2"), does anyone know why?:

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy
import shapefile
# Arcpy settings
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
# =======================
lstgrids = [[grid1],[grid2]
            ]
# loop
for i,item in enumerate(lstgrids):
    A,B = item

# Process: Project Raster
print 'project'
arcpy.ProjectRaster_management(A,B, "PROJCS['Belge_Lambert_1972',GEOGCS['GCS_Belge_1972',DATUM['D_Belge_1972',SPHEROID['International_1924',6378388.0,297.0]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Lambert_Conformal_Conic'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',150000.01256],PARAMETER['False_Northing',5400088.4378],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',4.367486666666666],PARAMETER['Standard_Parallel_1',49.8333339],PARAMETER['Standard_Parallel_2',51.16666723333333],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',90.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]]", "NEAREST", "100 100", "'Amersfoort_To_ETRS_1989_MB + Belge_1972_To_ETRS_1989_2'", "", "PROJCS['RD_New',GEOGCS['GCS_Amersfoort',DATUM['D_Amersfoort',SPHEROID['Bessel_1841',6377397.155,299.1528128]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Double_Stereographic'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',155000.0],PARAMETER['False_Northing',463000.0],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',5.38763888888889],PARAMETER['Scale_Factor',0.9999079],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',52.15616055555555],UNIT['Meter',1.0]]"
```

Comment: Please format your source code properly. And what output did you expect?

Answer (score 2):

Your for-loop seems to work just fine, you simply didn´t include the processing per each iteration. Your for-loop finishes iterating before any processing is done due to the processing block not being indented to be part of the loop.

Try this:

```
import arcpy
import shapefile

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

lstgrids = [[grid1],[grid2]]

for i,item in enumerate(lstgrids):

    A,B = item

    #proper indentation to include the following code in the for-loop
    print 'project'
    arcpy.ProjectRaster_management(A,B, "PROJCS['Belge_Lambert_1972',GEOGCS['GCS_Belge_1972',DATUM['D_Belge_1972',SPHEROID['International_1924',6378388.0,297.0]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Lambert_Conformal_Conic'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',150000.01256],PARAMETER['False_Northing',5400088.4378],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',4.367486666666666],PARAMETER['Standard_Parallel_1',49.8333339],PARAMETER['Standard_Parallel_2',51.16666723333333],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',90.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]]", "NEAREST", "100 100", "'Amersfoort_To_ETRS_1989_MB + Belge_1972_To_ETRS_1989_2'", "", "PROJCS['RD_New',GEOGCS['GCS_Amersfoort',DATUM['D_Amersfoort',SPHEROID['Bessel_1841',6377397.155,299.1528128]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Double_Stereographic'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',155000.0],PARAMETER['False_Northing',463000.0],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',5.38763888888889],PARAMETER['Scale_Factor',0.9999079],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',52.15616055555555],UNIT['Meter',1.0]]"
```

In this context, the for-loop and its statements could be rewritten in different (more simple, more pythonic) ways, but using your code this should do the trick (assuming all other parts are correct). 
Sidenote: again in this context, this question might actually be more suitable to the [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) site.